# JSTL Remove ALL session attributes

Tags: java, jsp, session, jstl

I have been googling and found that I can remove a session attribute using:

```
<c:remove var="foo" />
```

What I want is to **clear all session attributes from a JSP**, something like this:

```
<c:forEach  var="item" items="${sessionScope}">
    <c:remove var="${item }" scope="session"/>
</c:forEach>
```

The problem is that the code from above gives me this warning

**c:remove doesn't support runtime expression**

And I can't view the JSP where I put the code.

Is it possible? Is it a good practice to do something like this?

Comment: Why would you do that in a JSP, which is a view component used to generate HTML code? Do that in Java, inside your controller.

Comment: Ok, so It's a bad practice, I'm a newbie trying JSTL, anyway it's strange that you can remove a session attribute in the view.

Comment: You can do it. Just use a scriplet. <%session.removeAttribute("a");%> But, it is considered a sin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Because your are iterating through "item" and while iterating it inside loop you are trying to delete.**

Better do this logic in java only rather than JSP