# Browser Back button issue in jsp

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets

I am working with JSP and Servlets where I need to show the error page and I have to kill the session when user clicks on back button of the browser.I do not want to disable the back button of browser.
I am opening pages in IFrame of other application meanwhile I lost my application session.
If anybody find this type of issue please give me the solution.
Thanks.

Comment: You cannot disable the browsers back button. You can't use the back button if browsers history object reaches the first element (because it is an array).

Comment: You can use jquery plugin https://github.com/asual/jquery-address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error notice page is the end of browsing flow. Create file ***error_notice.jsp*** (have snippet `isErrorPage="true"`) like that:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" isErrorPage="true" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h2 style="color: red; text-align: center">There are something error! Please come back!</h2>
<%
    request.getSession().removeAttribute("anAttribute");
%>
</body>
</html>
```

If you want remove all session attributes, do this in Java code. See more:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/22120172/3728901

Comment: Thanks dovy for reply..